# Подскажите как разместить кнопку Instagram

Tags: html

Необходимо разместить кнопку еще одной социальной сети в верхнем правом углу сайта. Битрикс. www.ingkurort.ru

На данный момент код выглядит так:

Facebook

```
            <li><a href="https://vk.com/armhiru" title="Вконтакте" class="btn-social btn-social_vk">Вконтакте</a></li>

            <li><a href="https://instagram.com/armkhi/" title="Инстаграм" class="btn-social btn-social_in">Инстаграм</a></li>
        </ul><!-- /social -->
```

Кнопка Инстаграм кликабельна, но не видно ярлык. 
Последнюю часть кода добавил сам, скорее всего ошибка в имени класса class="btn-social btn-social_in" но не знаю что нужно указать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить иконку в изображение http://ingkurort.ru/bitrix/templates/armhi_copy/images/icons.png

в [ваш css-файл](http://ingkurort.ru/bitrix/templates/armhi_copy/css/style.css) добавить строку по образу и подобию 173 строки

```
.btn-social_ig:after {
  margin: -5px 0 0 -8px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 10px;
  background-position: -22px -39px;
}
```

и прописать нужные цифры (размер иконки и позицию иконки в png-файле)

Comment: Супер ответ. Оказывается все просто и при этом даже интересно. Все решил. Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Имя класса зависит от того что написано в css. В вашем случае для социальных кнопок прописана картинка http://ingkurort.ru/bitrix/templates/armhi_copy/images/icons.png И в ней только три соц-сети: ВК, твиттер и фейсбук. Инстаграмма нет.

Для того чтобы поставить значок инстаграмма, вам необходимо воспользоваться каким-нибудь набором значков соц-сетей.

Comment: а можно ли тогда в этот код подставить изображение значка Инстаграма?

Comment: Можно. Как-то так. Вместо instagram.png нужно поставить путь до картинки `<li><a href="https://instagram.com/armkhi/" title="Инстаграм" class="btn-social"><img src="instagram.png"></a></li>`